# In groovy, how would I split the output from a csv file based on comma(,)

Tags: groovy

If below is my output,

US,USACN,CanadaIN,India..

How would I split the above using the comma delimiter in Groovy.

And i would wish to write the same output to a CSV file.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: @cfrick 

This is what i'm trying

def csv = new File("C:/SoapUIWorkspace/TestData.csv")

def splitCountries = countries.split(',')

def myFile = new File( "C:/SoapUIWorkspace/TestData.csv" )

splitCountries.each { aCountry ->
    myFile << "$aCountry\n"
}

Below questions I've:
1. Willing to read from csv and write individual item to log output
2. Write individual item to a new sheet of same TestData.csv
3. How to acccess individual and specific cell. say 2nd row 3rd column

Answer (score 0):

```
//open output file for write
new File("file-name-out.csv").withWriter("UTF-8"){ writer->
    //open input file, read each line, and split by coma delimeter
    new File("file-name-in.csv").splitEachLine(",", "UTF-8"){ line->
        //you can do something with each line here
        //...
        //write line to output file with coma delimiter and add new line at the end
        writer.append(line.join(",")).append("\n")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following with a couple of examples

```
def input = new File( 'input.csv' )
def output = new File( 'output.csv' )

input.splitEachLine( ',' ){
    // write single item to file
    def item0 = it[0]
    println item0
    output << "$item0\n"

    // OR write multiple items to file
    output << "${it[0]},${it[3]}\n"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike.

I'm trying to run the below script.

def countries = 'US,USACN,CanadaIN,India'

def splitCountries = countries.split(',')

def myFile = new File( "C:/SoapUIWorkspace/TestData.csv" )

splitCountries.each { aCountry ->
    myFile << "$aCountry\n"
}

Output:
Ljava.lang.String:@670796e

Not sure where i'm going wrong. Can you please correct me.

Comment: So in your TestData.csv file you have the text 'Ljava.lang.String:@670796e' ?

Comment: Nope. On executing the script, "Ljava.lang.String:@670796e" is the output i'm getting.

Comment: What do you want it to output? That script was meant to just show how you break the string into individual components using split(',') then a couple of options for writing to a file

Comment: Lemme redefine my ask.

My task is to read data from CSV, display it to log output and write the same cell by cell to another csv.

when i try to read the data from csv, "US,USAIN,INDIACN,CANADA" is the output i'm getting. Hence, i wanted to split the output and store individual item to another csv.

Adding to it, how would i access a specific cell item?